# Shape Events Visual studio Tools for Office

Tags: vsto

By using the below code I created a Shape in Visual studio Tools for Office

private void Sheet01_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

this.Shapes.AddShape(Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeActionButtonCustom, 160, 461, 109, 20);

}

I want do some thing when I click on the shape.

Please help me to write events for this.

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't provide anythig for that.

If you are talking about an Excel add-in, the [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835842.aspx) class doesn't provide any event for that. I bielive you may find the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194470(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Worksheet class helpful. It is fired when the selection changes on a worksheet. So, you can check out the select object on sheet.